# jquery slider for 12 images with arrows

Tags: image, slider

Hi and sorry for my englis is not verry good.

I need a simple jquery script to slide 12 images (6 by 6) with arrows.
Arrows function is simple when click right arrow sliding me to other 6 images, and left arrow back me to first 6 images.
Thanks!

Comment: What did you tried? This is not an `request an script` site but an `help I'm stuck` site.

Comment: Im tried to slide 12 pictures (6 by 6) with arrow function (2 arrows one left and one right (when i click right arrow to slide me to more 6 pics)